# MySQL syntax errors inside my script

Tags: mysql, sql, geolocation, distance

I am getting this error from mysql:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long) *pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))as distance FROM wp_places_locator dest having dista' at line 1
```

when using this query:

```
set @orig_lat=121.9763; set @orig_lon=37.40445;
set @dist=10;
SELECT *,3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@orig_lat -abs(lat)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(@orig_lat * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(lat) *pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((@orig_lon - long) *pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))as distance
FROM wp_places_locator dest having distance < @dist
ORDER BY distance limit 10\G;
```

the code is adapted from here: http://arubin.org/files/geo_search.pdf to search my database for geolocation coordinates near coordinates it will recieve and sort them in order of distance from the recieved coordinates. 
any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: So run it in an interactive SQL shell. Slowly break down the query until you find the failing part, then fix it and reconstruct the query. (FWIW: `\G` looks blatantly wrong as part of a *statement*, it's for output formatting and might not work when used "from a script".)

Comment: can you reccomend an interactive SQL shell?

Comment: The [`mysqli` command-line tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html) (interactive), phpMyAdmin (not really interactive), or even http://sqlfiddle.com/ (for quick tests). There are probably many other clients available.

Comment: thanks, i'll use those in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word `long` is a reserved word.  You can find the list of words [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-7.html).

This means that you need to escape the name, typically using backticks.

Better yet, don't used reserved words as identifiers.